# hidden __len__ call in pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

`__len__` seems to be being called prematurely and without being detected by my debugger (vs studio).  Have a look at the simplified code below, which reproduces the problem.

```
class DataFrameReader:

    #
    def __init__(self, filePath, header=None, bufferLines=1000): 
        """docstring"""

        self._dataFrameReader = None
        self.BufferLines = bufferLines
        self._peekBuffer = None

        self._dataFrameReader = pd.read_csv(filePath,
            dtype=header, chunksize=bufferLines)

        return

    #
    def __len__(self): 
        """docstring"""

        lineCount = None
        if not self._peekBuffer:
            self._peekBuffer = next(self._dataFrameReader, [])

        lineCount = len(self._peekBuffer)

        return lineCount
```

When I create an instance of this class:

```
filePath = ((r'C:\Users\jmarshall\source\repos\')
            (r'First200_Base_TestDataFrameIO.csv'))
_dfr = DataFrameReader(filePath, bufferLines=25)
```

After i instantiate the dataframe TextReader (pd.read_csv) in line 11 the value of the variable `self._peekBuffer` becomes the first 25 records of the csv i'm reading formated as a data frame.

How can this happen?

The `self._peekBuffer` should only contain data once len is called on an instance of the DataFrameReader (ex. `len(_dfr)`).

It seems really crazy that `pd.read_csv` could know about the `__len__` method of its containing object and be able to call it.  Furthermore no break points get hit when I leave them in the `__len__` method, but if I comment out `__len__` then the the `self._peekBuffer` stays as `None` (how it should be!).

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems the native `open()` function also has the same hidden `__len__` call.  Also, i've since found out that if I put a `raise Exception` clause in my `__len__` CPython will eat it.  The error will definitely cause `__len__` to fail, but no output will be given regarding the error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga correct.  Sorry that was a typo copying the code from my editor.  The problem still exists, but I've fixed the typo.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the `\\` is necessary unless you want to align the variables within the brackets.

Comment: No it isn't. Parentheses have implicit line-continuation (indeed, according to PEP 8, you should prefer parentheses over \\)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just tested it.  Your right.

Comment: It seems more likely that your debugger is calling `__len__`, rather than that `pandas.read_csv` is doing it.

Comment: I am essentially certain that neither `pd.read_csv` nor `open` are calling `len` on your DataFrameReader object. In any event, I cannot reproduce, and after instantiation, `dfr._peekBuffer` is `None` and everything is working as expected. How exactly are you running this?

Comment: @user2357112 you know that may be true. Debuggers do all sorts of introspection into objects. This is probably because it wouldn't expect `len` to have any side-effects. Really, `len` *shouldn't* have side-effects.

Comment: I've written some tests now to verify that it is in fact the debugger.  I guess I could generally ignore this issue, now that I know the cause.  No production use case would ever involve inspecting private variables and any len() call will work consistently.  Does anyone want to post an answer so I close this?